# how the system recognize if the question is already answered

Tags: mysql, vb.net, loops, xampp, system

I want to know how the system recognize if the question is already answered or not if the user want to go back in previous question. if its already answered the answer will update either the score is increase or not or if the answer is not edited it will be the same.

BUTTON1 is to go back to previous quesion
Button2 is for checking if true or false the answwer
BUTTON 3 is for Keep going the exam

#### Here are my code snippets:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Public Class Exam
    'declaring variables for connection'
    Dim score As Integer
    Dim rightans As String
    Dim correct As Integer = 0
    Dim choice As String
    Dim choice1 As String
    Dim choice2 As String
    Dim choice3 As String
    Dim con As MySqlConnection
    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim read As MySqlDataReader
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Private Sub Exam_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'setting the radiobutton to false, so that when the form load there is no shaded button'
        Label2.Text = 1
        A.Checked = False
        B.Checked = False
        C.Checked = False
        D.Checked = False
        con = New MySqlConnection

        Button1.Enabled = False
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=user;"
        'calling sub
        qno()



    End Sub


Sub clear()
        'to set the radiobutton false/no shaded.
        A.Checked = False
        B.Checked = False
        C.Checked = False
        D.Checked = False
    End Sub

    Sub qno()
        'calling connection'
        Try
            con = New MySqlConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=user;"
            con.Open()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM user.math WHERE question_id = @ID;"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand
            With COMMAND
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label2.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            Dim arrImage() As Byte
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                arrImage = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)

                Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)

                Pic1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
                question.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
                A.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
                B.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
                C.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
                D.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)

            Else
                MsgBox("No results!")
            End If
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            da.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Sub increment()
        'incrementing the score f the answer is correct'
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        i = Label2.Text
        i = i + 1
        Label2.Text = i
        If Label2.Text > 1 Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub decrement()
        'incrementing the score f the answer is correct'
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        i = Label2.Text
        i = i - 1
        Label2.Text = i
        If Label2.Text = 1 Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'checking of the user answer the questions'
        If ((A.Checked = False) And (B.Checked = False) And (C.Checked = False) And (D.Checked = False)) Then
            MsgBox("Please answer the question")

        Else
            'if the examinee answers all the examination it will call another questions from database'
            If A.Checked = True Then
                con.Open()
                ' Dim ans As String
                Dim arren As String = "A"
                Dim sql As String = ("select answer from user.math where question_id = '" & Label2.Text & "' ")
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
                Dim it As String

                read = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
                If read.HasRows Then
                    If read.Read Then
                        it = read.Item("answer")
                        If it = choice Then
                            correct = correct + 1
                            Label4.Text = correct
                        ElseIf it <> choice And Label2.Text <= 1 Then
                            correct = correct - 1
                            Label4.Text = correct
                        End If

                    End If

                    clear()


                End If


                If Label2.Text = 10 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("proceed to other subject test")
                End If
                con.Close()




    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        decrement()
        qno()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There's way too much code there and your question is too vague.  You need to very specific about the question and only post code that is relevant to that question.  If you're basically saying "this is what I've done, how do I do the rest" then that's not really for us to answer.  Whatever you want to do, you need to attempt to do first and then you can ask why if it doesn't work.  You would then post only code relevant to that issue specifically.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. This will help you avoid runtime errors.

Comment: It would be helpful if you named your buttons something meaningful. Button2 looks like Accept Answer but Button1 and Button3 don't make much sense.

Comment: You are checking what radio button is checked in Button2 so why all these checked changed events?

Comment: Get rid of the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` in the Sub qno. Select statements are queries returning rows and you execute the command with `da.Fill(dt)`

Comment: You have downloaded the answer column in the `da.Fill(dt)` How about keeping it in a hidden label or the tag property of the question control instead of downloading it again in Button2.

Comment: You are incrementing and decrementing in Button2 so why do you need separate Subs for this?

Comment: increment is to keep going the exam . and the purpose of decrement is to go back to already answered question. the main problem of my system is the system cant handle if the previous question are already answered or not. and if the answer is true the score is keep incrementing lol.

Answer (score 0):

Untested since I don't have your database. Comments above and inline.

```
Public Class Form3

    Dim correct As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Exam_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'setting the radiobutton to false, so that when the form load there is no shaded button'
        Label2.Text = "1"
        A.Checked = False
        B.Checked = False
        C.Checked = False
        D.Checked = False
        Button1.Enabled = False
        qno()
    End Sub
    Private Sub clear()
        'to set the radiobutton false/no shaded.
        A.Checked = False
        B.Checked = False
        C.Checked = False
        D.Checked = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub qno()
        Try
            'Using...End Using blocks will close and dispose of your objects
            Using con = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=user;")
                Using Cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user.math WHERE question_id = @ID;", con)
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Label2.Text)
                    Dim arrImage() As Byte
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter
                        da.SelectCommand = Cmd
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                            'Not at all sure about this picture code
                            arrImage = CType(dt.Rows(0).Item(7), Byte())
                            Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)
                            Pic1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
                            question.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
                            A.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
                            B.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
                            C.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4).ToString
                            D.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5).ToString
                            'guessing that answer it item 6
                            HiddenLabel.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
                        Else
                            MsgBox("No results!")
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'checking of the user answer the questions'
        If ((A.Checked = False) And (B.Checked = False) And (C.Checked = False) And (D.Checked = False)) Then
            MsgBox("Please answer the question")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'The correct answer was put in the HiddenLabel.Text (Visible set to False)
        'in the qno Sub
        Dim CorrectAnswer As String = HiddenLabel.Text
        Dim UserChoice As String = ""

        If A.Checked Then
            UserChoice = "A"
        ElseIf B.Checked Then
            UserChoice = "B"
        ElseIf C.Checked Then
            UserChoice = "C"
        Else
            UserChoice = "D"
        End If

        If UserChoice = CorrectAnswer Then
            correct += 1
        Else
            'It is very hard to get a good score if it is decremented with every wrong answer
            'Why not skip this and just give a zero for a wrong answer
            correct -= 1
        End If
        Label4.Text = correct.ToString
        clear()
        If Label2.Text = "10" Then
            MessageBox.Show("proceed to other subject test")
            Me.Hide()
            exam2.Show()
        Else
            'Add code to keep track of question number in 
            'Add code to show the next question
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: how if the user want to go back to other question and edit it? how the system if the score is to decrement or not or its still be the same?

Comment: If you allow the user to go back and change his answer, he will keep going back until he sees his score go up.

Comment: what if i dont want to show the score and its automatically save to database?

Comment: If you want to allow users to go back you will have to save the answers to each question then display the answer for the previous question. Since you are scoring as you go along you need to reverse the score for the previous question by checking again if it is right or wrong and incrementing if wrong and decrementing if correct. You are really complicating your code be adding this feature.